# How to bind label text placed inside a split Button Content with the selected List box item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to create a drop-down like control using WPF split button. I can get drop down working but what I want to achieve next is that if a user select an item from dropdown menu, that text is updated as split Button Content. Also, By default when this control is loaded, first item name is set to split button content.

My preference is to do it in xaml itself.

Here's existing code:

```
<userControls:BaseUserControl x:Class="UserControls.TestControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"              
         xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:MainAssembly.UserControls"
         xmlns:const="clr-namespace:MainAssembly.const"
         xmlns:toolkit="abc/Wpf.Toolkit"
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<userControls:BaseUserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <toolkit:NullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullToVisibilityConverter" />
        <toolkit:MultiValueToObjectArrayConverter x:Key="MultiValueToObjectArrayConverter" />
        <toolkit:BoolToInvertedBoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToInvertedBoolToVisibilityConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</userControls:BaseUserControl.Resources>

<xctk:SplitButton Name="TestSplitBtn" ToolBar.OverflowMode="AsNeeded"
                                          Margin="5,1,5,1"
                                          >
    <xctk:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
        <ListBox Name="DropDownMenu" Margin="5,1,5,5"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding DropDownContentCollection}"
                                  ToolBar.OverflowMode="AsNeeded"                                                                        
                                  Visibility="{Binding DropDownContentCollection, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                  ToolTip="{x:Static const:const.toolTip}"
                                      MaxWidth="150">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Style="{DynamicResource TransparentButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding DataContext.TestCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource Icon_Test}" Margin="4,0,5,0" Height="16" Width="16" />
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock.Text>
                                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{} {0}({1})">
                                            <Binding Path="Name" />
                                            <Binding Path="ImageCount" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </TextBlock.Text>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Style>
        </ListBox>
    </xctk:SplitButton.DropDownContent>

    <xctk:SplitButton.Content>
        <toolkit:LabelledButton x:Name="TestSeries"
                                                        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="TestBtn"
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding ViewerState}" Margin="0,1,0,0" Height="56">
            <toolkit:LabelledButton.Content>
                <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource Icon_Test}" Margin="0,2,0,-5"/>

            </toolkit:LabelledButton.Content>
            <toolkit:LabelledButton.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:LabelledButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type toolkit:LabelledButton}}">
                    <Setter Property="LabelText" Value="{Binding SelectedImageSeries, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding SelectedImageSeries, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </toolkit:LabelledButton.Style>
        </toolkit:LabelledButton>
    </xctk:SplitButton.Content>

    <xctk:SplitButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:SplitButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TestSplitButtonStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </Style>
    </xctk:SplitButton.Style>
</xctk:SplitButton>
```

Also, when I click on the button, It execute the command associated but dropdown menu doesn't get closed.

Comment: What are you doing with the selected item? How do you use it? Where is  `DropDownContentCollection` defined? You have also already added a `Rectangle` as button's content. How do you want to display the selected item, where and which properties?

Comment: @BionicCode DropDownContentCollection is an observable collection defined in associated view model for this user control. When this whole control is displayed on UI, you have option to select items from the collection. On selection, it will execute "TestCommand" associated with it, which will update UI.

Comment: Then add another property to the view model and bind the `ListBox.SelectedItem` to it. Use the same property to bind the button's  content.

Comment: @BionicCode I have already added the binding, but it's not working. ~<Setter Property="LabelText" Value="{Binding SelectedImageSeries, Mode=TwoWay}" />~

Answer (score 0):

You also have to bind the `ListBox.SelectedItem` property to `SelectedImageSeries`.

It looks like your are using the `SplitButton` too complicated. I've posted a simplified solution. 
Since we are now properly binding the `SelectedImageSeries` item from the `ListBox`, there is no need to add a `Button` to the `DataTemplate` of the `ListBoxItem`.
Instead of executing the `TestCommand`, you can handle the selected item directly in the property setter. I have added a method `OnSelectedImageSeriesChanged` to the view model for this purpose.

There is also no need to add another button (`LabelButton`) nested into the `SplitButton.Content`. You can modify the content layout by assigning a `DataTemplate` to `SplitButton.ContentTemplate` and bind a `ICommand` to the `SplitButton.Command` property and optionally use `SplitButton.CommandParameter`.

`BindingMode.TwoWay` is only required when you send back data to the data source. It's  redundant in every place you have used it: `LabelText` and `ToolTip` never send data (they can't). Most of the properties that can send data as they are reflecting user input are binding `TwoWay` by default e.g., `TextBox.Text`, `ListBox.SelectedItem`, `ToggleButton.IsChecked` etc.

**View Model**

```
class MainViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<ImageSeries> DropDownContentCollection { get; }

  private ImageSeries selectedImageSeries;   
  public ImageSeries SelectedImageSeries
  {
    get => this.selectedImageSeries;
    set 
    { 
      this.selectedImageSeries = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();

      // Handle ListBox item selected. Replaces command.
      OnSelectedImageSeriesChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**SplitButton**

```
<xctk:SplitButton Width="100" 
                  Content="{Binding SelectedImageSeries}"
                  Command="{Binding HandleButtonPressedCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding ViewerState}">
  <xctk:SplitButton.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource Icon_Test}" Width="20" Height="20" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </xctk:SplitButton.ContentTemplate>
  <xctk:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DropDownContentCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImageSeries}" />
  </xctk:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
</xctk:SplitButton>
```